# Java - simple drawing application

Tags: java, swing, awt

I need to make a simple drawing application which is able to draw a line, a *rectangle and a circle* between *2 user-given points*.

The exact application behavior should look like this:

1. User clicks on a button to enable certain shape drawing i.e. "Line",
2. Moves his mouse to a `JPanel` which makes the cursor change to a
   crosshair
3. User clicks two times which draws two points (small circles) and the
   selected shape is drawn between the two points

So far this is what I've came up with:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;

public class MainFrame
{
    private boolean readyToDraw = false;
    private int clickCount = 0;
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel drawPanel;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MainFrame window = new MainFrame();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public MainFrame() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 800, 600);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        buttonPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0), 2, true));
        buttonPanel.setBounds(10, 11, 100, 85);
        frame.getContentPane().add(buttonPanel);
        buttonPanel.setLayout(null);

        JButton btnLine = new JButton("Line");
        btnLine.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        btnLine.setBounds(4, 4, 92, 25);

        btnLine.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // Execute when button is pressed
                if (readyToDraw == true) {
                    System.out.println("Let's draw!");
                }

                else {

                }
                System.out.println("Line");

            }
        });

        JButton btnRectangle = new JButton("Rectangle");
        btnRectangle.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        btnRectangle.setBounds(4, 30, 92, 25);

        btnRectangle.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // Execute when button is pressed
                if (readyToDraw == true) {
                    System.out.println("Let's draw!");
                }

                else {

                }
                System.out.println("Rectangle");
            }
        });

        JButton btnCircle = new JButton("Circle");
        btnCircle.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        btnCircle.setBounds(4, 56, 92, 25);

        btnCircle.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // Execute when button is pressed
                if (readyToDraw == true) {
                    System.out.println("Let's draw!");
                }

                else {

                }
                System.out.println("Circle");
            }
        });

        buttonPanel.add(btnLine);
        buttonPanel.add(btnRectangle);
        buttonPanel.add(btnCircle);
    }
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
private class Paint extends JPanel implements MouseListener{
    drawPanel = new JPanel();
    drawPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    drawPanel.setBounds(120, 11, 664, 550);
    frame.getContentPane().add(drawPanel);

    this.addMouseListener(new MouseListener());

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
        Cursor dotCursor = new Cursor(Cursor.CROSSHAIR_CURSOR);
        drawPanel.setCursor(dotCursor);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        int x1 = 0;
        int y1 = 0;
        int x2 = 0;
        int y2 = 0;
        if (clickCount == 0) {
            x1 = e.getX();
            y1 = e.getY();
            clickCount++;
        } else if (clickCount == 1) {
            x2 = e.getX();
            y2 = e.getY();
            clickCount++;
            readyToDraw = true;
        } else {
            clickCount = 0;
            readyToDraw = false;
        }

        System.out.println(x1 + " " + y1 + " " + clickCount + " " + x2 + " "
                + y2 + readyToDraw);
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


 }
}
```

This contains some errors which I am unable to resolve. What I need is an explanation of how to make my application to be able to at least draw a line.

Comment: Really? "This contains some errors" But you aren't going to tell us what they are?

Comment: I would tell you if I knew exactly what they are. The Eclipse console output doesn't tells only this:
 `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation    problem: 
 at MainFrame.main(MainFrame.java:22)`

I suppose there are syntax problems at insertion of a class into main class.

Comment: I realized that some text at the end had disappeared somehow and by question became unclear. I edited my question a little.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Paint` class, you seem to trying to execute functionality outside of the context of a method or constructor...

```
private class Paint extends JPanel implements MouseListener {

    // Undefined variable...
    drawPanel  = new JPanel();

    // Executing functionality outside of a method or constructor
    drawPanel.setBackground (Color.WHITE);

    drawPanel.setBounds (

    120, 11, 664, 550);
    frame.getContentPane ()
    .add(drawPanel);



    this.addMouseListener(

    new MouseListener());
```

So, you could do something like...

```
private class Paint extends JPanel implements MouseListener {

    private JPanel drawPanel = new JPanel();

    public Paint() {
        drawPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        drawPanel.setBounds(
                        120, 11, 664, 550);
        frame.getContentPane()
                        .add(drawPanel);

        this.addMouseListener(
                        new MouseListener());

    }
```

But that will end up with an error on the `this.addMouseListener` call, because `MouseListener` is an interface and needs to be implemented before it can be used, but guess what, you can just do `this.addMouseListener(this);`

That takes care of compiler errors, but there are a bunch of logic errors...

You seem to create an instance of a `JPanel`, within a `JPanel` class (`drawPanel` in `JPanel`) and then add this child panel (`drawPanel`) to the `frame` directly!?  That seems like a complete waste of time and, generally speaking, is simply bad design...

However, you then add a `MouseListener` to the `Paint` panel and then try and use it to update the `drawPanel`....????

Simply speaking, you don't need `drawPanel`, just get rid of it and use the `Paint` panel directly (but don't add it to the frame from within the constructor of `Paint`, `Paint` shouldn't care)

Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: I use `setLayout(null)` only to center the application window. As for pixel perfect layouts, since this is my first GUI application, I try to simplify things to avoid brain damage from all the possibilities out there. Anyways, thank you for your answer, this should solve the existing errors.

Comment: You could use `GridBagLayout` to center components around the center of the window, using `pack` and `setLocationRelativeTo(null)` on the frame will center the window on the screen, but are really only useful when use with layout managers.